# dtexec /SET package variable value not being used by package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, dtexec

I'm using SQL Server 2012 & MS Visual Studio 2010

I have a DTS package with a user variable, `PO` (string), and I'm trying to execute a sql command using that variable, so I've set up another variable to build the sql string.

The problem is, that when I try to run the package using the `DTEXEC` utility with `/SET`, the package is ignoring the variable value I'm sending.

Command I'm using:

```
dtexec /server myserver /sql MyPackageName /U user /P password /SET "\Package.Variables[User::PO].Properties[Value]";"AE-J067329-01"
```

The expression for `SQLStringVar` is `"exec my_procedure '" + @[User::PO] + "'"`

However, the results show `SQLStringVar` as evaluating to `"exec my_procedure ''"` , or whatever value I put for the initial value for the `User::PO` variable. The package runs without errors.

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved by accepting it, rather than appending 'solved' to the title. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
In the Package Explorer tab...Variables.

Right-click the variable, go to Properties, and change EvaluateAsExpression to False.

(This was driving me nuts since, when editing the variable using the Variables tab, this property is not available)